# Picture Mishnayos for Masechtas Mikvaos

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna, mikvah-ritual-bath, maseches-mikvaos

Does anybody know any good picture mishnayos for masechtas mikvaos. There is no Mishnah Behirah on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend artscroll Yad Avrohom series here http://artscroll.com/Items.aspx?hierId=MIS&rewrite=165&page=2 which had a lot of pictures where words alone could not explain.

It really helped me when I learnt keilim and I normally don't learn from English seforim but in this case it was indispensable and I would say better knowledge than pride.